# CQRS : Injecting a messageBus in CommandHandlers

Tags: php, messaging, cqrs

Does it sound like a correct approach to **inject the whole Bus in commandHandlers** so the latter could call `$this->messageBus->dispatch($events);`

```
class OneCommandHandler
{
   private $messageBus;

   //.....

   public function handle(Command $command)
   {
     //..... will at some points hopefully returns DomainEvents
   }

   private function dispatch(DomainEvents $events)
   {
     $this->messageBus->dispatch($events);
   }
}
```

Isn’t it too much coupling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would even say it is recommended since in your command handler you most probably will want to reply back to the originator with the processing status and the only way to do this is to engage the bus reply/response functionality.

As it was discussed in the DDD/CRQS Google group, there are no such thing as "one way (or "fire and forget") commands" since command means action, a state change and this can fail, leaving the system in undefined state if the failure is not handler properly, comparing to a query that is idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you could keep things under control; like using dependency injection framework or a (not overabused) service locator; I think it is OK injecting the bus into Domain Services.

About having the repository... What about add another layer just to keep Domain Services in persistence ignorance?

What I mean is that if `OneCommandHandler` is to apply Domain rules and fire Domain events then belongs to Domain Services Layer. Domain should not have dependencies. Domain should apply rules and invariants and coordinate the operations of aggregates. All this should be input parametes of Domain operations. Maybe you need a Application Service Layer as a coordinator of application services (security, logging, persistence, etc) and Domain services.

i.e.:

```
class ProductApplicationService
{
  function ProductNameExchange($productExchangeComand){

      LoggingAppService.LogAction("User ask to exchange product names");
      SecurityAppService.AuthorizeCommand($productExchangeComand);
      $productAggregate1 = ProductRepository.getProductById($productExchangeComand.firsProductId);
      $productAggregate2 = ProductRepository.getProductById($productExchangeComand.secondProductId);

      //rules and invariants
      ProductDomainService.ExchangeNames($productAggregate1, $productAggregate2); 

   }
}

class ProductDomainService{

    function ExchangeNames($productAggregate1, $productAggregate2)(){
    //code to coordinate the 2 aggregates
    $aux = $productAggregate1.name;
    $productAggregate1.setName($productAggregate2.name); //$productAggregate has its own rules to change its name
    $productAggregate2.setName($aux);

  }

}
```

Comment: Step 4 : i disagree - there's no such thing like `message handlers subscriptors` for commands, as command and handler is in a 1:1 relationship

Comment: But the interesting point is Step 5 : Domain Service (aka. `CommandHandler`) handles the message (see my `function handle($command)` in my question) and **send events to the bus**. That's indeed my question. How should that best happen? I was proposing the service having the bus injected

Comment: But as the handler will have the eventStreamRepository injected anyway (to reconstitue the aggregate from the eventStream), another solution could be the latter being composed by the bus. What do you think?

Comment: First of all. I think I missunderstood your question. You are right and you are already doing what I am posting. I am going to full edit it. I am sorry.

Comment: Dont be sorry while trying to help ;-)